# Max pool size reached in while using threading in c# code

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I have a console application where i want to use threads. In the thread i am opening connection where at some point of time it breaks with the error

> *The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool*.

Here is my connection string

> connectionString="Data Source=INBLRWIT058068\SQL2008R2;Initial Catalog=OMApp;Integrated Security=SSPI;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=500;Max Pool Size=2000" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

Here is the C# code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WithThread();
}

private static void WithThread()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1500; i++)
    {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(GetOrders)); 
        thread1.Start();
    }
}


public static void GetOrders()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetOrders", connection))
        {
            command.CommandTimeout = 2;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            connection.Open();

            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}", reader[0], reader[1]));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help?

Comment: But why? Why are you creating **1500** threads here? There is going to be tremendous overhead related to that many threads, why aren't you using the threadpool or something similar instead?

Comment: You should explain your overall goal as there is likely a better way than 1.5k threads

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the max pool size with `1500`.

Comment: Lasse, my requirement is that.  I will create 1000s of orders (entity basically) and save it into database. Then another thread will pick up each entity and complete in the workflow.

Comment: No difference if we set the max pool size to 1500 or 10000